# Runner type : SSH exec not found in teamcity

Tags: git, build, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I am new to Teamcity. I am trying to do some Build configurations on it.

As of now I did some configurations but when I am trying to add a new build with Runner type: SSH exec, I am not getting this build step in the drop down.

You can see in below image

[image]

If there are any configuration I need to follow to get SSH EXEC in Teamcity build step please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

SSH exec runner is available inside [Deployer plugin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Deployer+plugin).
You can download the latest build from [here](https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/viewLog.html?buildId=796961&tab=artifacts&buildTypeId=bt402). To install it, drop the archive without unpacking in `<TEAMCITY_DATA_DIRECORY>/plugins`

It will be bundled in TeamCity 10.0

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> `SSH-Agent` - 
>      use ssh-agent for authentication, the SSH-Agent build feature must be **enabled**.

---

#### How to enable the `SSH-Agent`?

1. Upload your key to TeamCity server
2. Set up an ssh-agent build feature for your build
3. Choose ssh-agent auth. type in ssh deployer settings.

The deployer plugin can be found here:
https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-deployer-plugin