# Not able to run the build due to Incompatible Agents

Tags: ssh, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I am a Teamcity developer. We currently have many builds running on the Instance. But when i add new build which is a "SSH Exec" build step and want to run some commands on one of the instance. 
But i am not able to run the build because Agents are in Incompatible mode

[image: This is the Snapshot of my Error]

FYI 
I had some other build which are "SSH Exec" builds which are running fine 
How should i fix this. Please do the needfull.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can Any one help out on this

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965329/runner-type-ssh-exec-not-found-in-teamcity